# Mongoose access to subdocument with key from req.body

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

i need you're 200 IQ !! :)

I have a schema like this:

```
var ProgramSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
  day1: {
    phase1: {
      exercise1: {
        name: { type: String },
        repetition: { type: String },
        tst: { type: String },
        tdrp: { type: String },
        method: { type: String },
        weightKilo: { type: String },
      },
```

...

And i want update of name, repetition, tst ...

My req.body is :

```
{
userId: '5f9894d8a987136735f4c62e',
programId: '5fad83103c8b262bd9cdaa10',
day: 'day1',
phase: 'phase1',
exercise: 'exercise1',
exerciseName: 'Test',
repetition: '3x15',
tst: '1',
tdrp: '1',
method: 'Test',
weightKilo: '32'
}
```

We can use [req.body.key]: value for update key from req.body.
We can update subdocument with "key1.key2.key3": value
But i don't know how update subdocument with many key from req.body.

My last test :( :

```
Program.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: req.body.programId },
    {
      "[req.body.day].[req.body.phase].[req.body.exercise].name":
        req.body.exerciseName,
      "[req.body.day].[req.body.phase].[req.body.exercise].repetition":
        req.body.repetition,
      "[req.body.day].[req.body.phase].[req.body.exercise].tst": req.body.tst,
      "[req.body.day].[req.body.phase].[req.body.exercise].tdrp": req.body.tdrp,
      "[req.body.day].[req.body.phase].[req.body.exercise].method":
        req.body.method,
      "[req.body.day].[req.body.phase].[req.body.exercise].weightKilo":
        req.body.weightKilo,
    },
    { new: true },
    (err, obj) => {
      console.log("OBJ -->> ", obj);
      if (err) {
        res.json(false);
      } else {
        res.json(true);
      }
    }
  );
```

I need help :') Thx guy's !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your own query object like this:

```js
var name = req.body.day+"."+req.body.phase+"."+req.body.exercise+".name"
var query = {}
query[name] = req.body.exerciseName
```

And then update using this:

```js
var update = await model.updateOne({"id": req.body.programId},{$set:query})
```

This is an example how to do with one field, the rest should be in the same way.

Edit to say I have tested this and works perfectly:

```js
// Initialize keys names
var name = req.body.day+"."+req.body.phase+"."+req.body.exercise+".name"
var repetition = req.body.day+"."+req.body.phase+"."+req.body.exercise+".repetition";
var tst = req.body.day+"."+req.body.phase+"."+req.body.exercise+".tst";
var tdrp = req.body.day+"."+req.body.phase+"."+req.body.exercise+".tdrp";
var method = req.body.day+"."+req.body.phase+"."+req.body.exercise+".method";
var weightKilo = req.body.day+"."+req.body.phase+"."+req.body.exercise+".weightKilo";

// Add keys with values to the query
var query = {}
query[name] = req.body.exerciseName
query[repetition] = req.body.repetition
query[tst] = req.body.tst
query[tdrp] = req.body.tdrp
query[method] = req.body.method
query[weightKilo] = req.body.weightKilo

// Do the query
var update = await model.updateOne({_id:req.body.programId},{$set:query})
```

Comment: Hey J.F. it's perfect, that resolve my problem !! Thank you very much for you're help !